# artifactory: import repository from disk into an existing local repository

Tags: artifactory

I wonder what happens when I import a repository from disk into a non-empty local target repository. Does this overwrite existing artifacts? Or even, does this delete new ones in the local repo?

(I think it will be "merged" - but I don't want to test it on a prod system)

Regards
Marco

Answer (score 4):

When doing "**Repository import**" then the action will be merge.

PLEASE NOTE that in a case of "**Full System Import**" it will delete the existing content from existing repositories.